# How to create, sign and send transaction to Magiceden program

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter, send-transaction, instructions, transaction, magiceden

I have Magiceden API bearer token and using the [buyNow endpoint](https://docs.magiceden.io/reference/get_instructions-buy-now)

Which return Buffer data as in the picture. [image]

I tried to create the Transaction like this:

1. `const transactionME = Transaction.from(Buffer.from(data.ix.txSigned.data))`
2. `const transactionME = VersionedTransaction.deserialize(Buffer.from(data.ix.v0.txSigned.data))`

Then sign like this using the wallet adapter:

```
const signedTxns = await signAllTransactions([transactionME])
```

Then send like this:

1. `const signature = await sendTransaction(transaction, connection);`
2. `let sig = await conn.connection.sendRawTransaction(signedTxns[i].serialize(), preflightCommitment: "confirmed",skipPreflight: false})`

But always getting the following error:

```
"Program log: AnchorError caused by account: seller_trade_state. Error Code: AccountNotInitialized. Error Number: 3012. Error Message: The program expected this account to be already initialized."
```

I even tried to create everything from IDL getting exactly the same error:
[image]

I really do not understand how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken a quick glance at my ME API integration code from last year and this was the process for the buy-now endpoint which worked at the time (and I believe still works to this day):

```
const sellTransaction = Transaction.from(response.txSigned.data)
const signedTransaction = await signTransaction(sellTransaction)
const signature = await connection.sendRawTransaction(signedTransaction.serialize())

// optionally, listen to the signature after the transaction has been sent
```

I believe your ME integration is correct but the issue is on some other (semi-related) end. Have you tried reaching out to the ME team?

Let me know if this code snippet works for you! If not, I'll try investigating more.